# Pulling Github archive with Curl and Oauth token

Tags: authentication, curl, github, oauth

I want to pull the source files from a particular Github repository and a specific release (tag).

I use the following command:

```
curl -v -L -o website.tar.gz  -H "Authorization: token mypersonaltoken" https://github.com/my_org/some_project/archive/0.1.tar.gz
```

But the result is 406 not acceptable.

The Token I'm using is a personal token generated in my private account. The archive I'm pulling is in another account, where I have admin rights.

if I use:

```
curl -v -L -o website.tar.gz  -u myuser:mypassword https://github.com/my_org/some_project/archive/0.1.tar.gz
```

the download succeed.

How can I download this archive without using username and password

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented my way to this solution:

```
curl -L -u myusername:mypersonaltoken ...
```

The difference is that I use a 'Personal Token' instead of my password.